# Cancelling UIView Animation - self.view.layer removeAllAnimations not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

I've got a UIView Animation going on that I need to cancel in my iOS app.  I've tried this:

```
[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

But it didn't work.  The animation continued.  Here is my animation code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(recognizer.view.transform, translation.x, translation.y);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            NSLog(@"completed animation, now do whatever");
        }];
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to why it's not working?

Comment: You are adding that animation to recognizer view, hence you will have to remove it from that same view's layer. So instead of [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations] you may want to [recognizer.view.layer removeAllAnimations].

Comment: Hi.  Thanks - something is now happening, but that introduces another problem.  It takes the animation to the end instantly stopping it there.  I want it to stop in it's current position - the position it is in when I want to stop the animation - not jump to the end.  Can this be done like this?

Comment: Check out `recognizer.view.layer.presentationLayer`. It will have the middle transform, just set that to the current layer: `recognizer.view.layer.transform = recognizer.view.layer.presentationLayer.transform;` ... Might need more work.

Comment: Getting this error with your line for keeping the current status of the object when it's being animated: "Property 'transform' not found on object of type 'id'"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are adding that animation to recognizer's view, hence you will have to remove it from that same view's layer.

So instead of

```
[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

you may want to

```
[recognizer.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

And to keep the current status of the transformation, fetch that one from the presentation layer. The presentation layer is the one that actually reflects the changes during the animation.

```
recognizer.view.layer.transform = recognizer.view.layer.presentationLayer.transform;
```

Comment: Thanks for first 2.  Problem with the last section for keeping the status.  Get this error: "Property 'transform' not found on object of type 'id'"

Answer (score 3):

Ok - just figured it out.  Changed the component beng animated from the gesture recogniser on top of the image view to the image view itself.  Now, just before the code to stop the animation, I have:

```
 truckView.frame = [[trackView.layer presentationLayer] frame];
 [truckView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

So this is the way to do it.  Thanks for the help that led me to this answer,

Sam

Comment: I'm using this but starting to think because it gets the frame before remove all animations, the animation actually continues a little bit and the frame that was set is outdated